# How to calculate the exact probability that the sum of a sliding window over a list of boolean values equals to m?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of random boolean values of size $n$ with the probability of each value being true $p$:
$$
a_n=\left\{\begin{align*}
0, \quad & \text{if } \mathrm{random}(p) < 0.5 \\
1, \quad & \text{if } \mathrm{random}(p) \ge 0.5 \\
\end{align*}\right.
$$

Let a sequence $b_m$ be a sliding window of size $m$ over the sequence $a_n$ that is defined as:
$$
b_{m}=\{a_{i},a_{i+1},\dots,a_{i+m-1}\}, i=\overline{1,n-m-1}
$$

How can I find the exact probability that at least one of the sliding windows $b_m$ contains exactly $m$ true values?

**My own investigation**

Usually we calculate probability of "at least one" as $1-P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is the probability of the event *not* happening. But how can I find $P(A)$?

The problem is that the sliding windows overlap with each other, meaning the events are interdependent.
If the events were independent, I could compute PDF of binomial distribution for $m$ successes of $m$ trials and raise it to $n-m-1$:
$$P(B)=\left(1-p^m\right)^{n-m-1} \tag{1}$$
But it's not the case for dependent events.

I used Monte-Carlo simulation to obtain approximate probability of $1-P(A)$ with $n=10,m=5,p=\frac{1}{2}$:

```
import random


def generate_random_boolean_array(size: int, probability: float):
    return [random.random() >= probability for _ in range(size)]


total = 10**5
success = 0

n = 10
m = 5
p = 0.5

for _ in range(total):
    count = 0

    a = generate_random_boolean_array(n, p)
    for i in range(n - m + 1):
        if sum(a[i:i+m]) == m:
            count += 1

    if count > 0:
        success += 1


print(success / total)
```

The approximate probability that at least one of the sliding windows $b_m$ contains exactly $m$ true values is $0.11$. How can I find the exact probability using probability theory?

I think, the probability of the first sliding window is not dependent on other sliding windows, since it contains all new random boolean values. So I think it can be computed using equation $(1)$.
If we denote $P(C)$ to be the probability of the next sliding window *not* to have $m$ true values, will this probability be the same for all sliding windows except the first one?
If it will, then the probability I am looking for would be equal to:
$$P(A)=P(B) \cdot P(C)^{m-n-1-1}$$

Intuitively, the next sliding window is dependent on $m-1$ previous boolean values, and $1$ new boolean value.
Can I find $P(C)$ in this case?

P.S.:
I'm a student and I want to solve this problem for educational purposes, to understand the math, not to just get the approximate probability using simulation, which would be enough for practical purposes.

Comment: You could define $A_m$ as the event that window $b_m$ shows $m$ true values and then go for finding $P(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-m+1}A_m)$ by applying the [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Nevertheless I would only recommend that if $n$ does not exceed $m$ too much. The intersections that you have too deal with are not nice.